# FlatList in Modal didn't load all data

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I show a FlatList, in Modal, but it's not load all data, just 42 item(from 0 to 41). I try ListView but the same and i don't understand why? Some can help me in this case, thank very much. This is my code with FlatList:

```
<ScrollView>
               <FlatList
                 data={this.state.dataSource}
                 renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                   <CountryItem item={item} index={index}/>
                 )}
                 horizontal={false}
                 onEndThreshold={0}
                 keyExtractor={item => ''.concat(Math.random())}
               />
             </ScrollView>
```

and it't not work, try with ListView, it't not work too

```
<StyleModal
    animationType="fade"
    transparent={true}
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => { }}>
    <StyleModalView>
        <StyleViewContent>
            <StyleViewHeader>
                <StyleTextHeader text={this.props.name} />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.closeModal}>
                    <StyledIcon
                        tintColor={'black'}
                        source={require('../assets/searchbox-clear.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </StyleViewHeader>

            <StyleListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}/>

        </StyleViewContent>
    </StyleModalView>
</StyleModal>
```

Comment: initialNumToRender={60}
maxToRenderPerBatch={60}

try with these 2 props

Comment: @anilsidhu It's not working